# maven archetype assembly failure on dashclassifier

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-archetype, archetypes

i have a archetype project which has a assembly.xml inside archetype-resources. it all worked fine till i had to change this

```
<unpack>false</unpack>
<outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}-${artifact.baseVersion}${dashClassifier?}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
```

in `<dependencyset>`. 
For some reason the `clean install` gives an error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.1:integration-
test (default-integration-test) on project  jetxyz:
[ERROR] Archetype IT 'basic' failed: org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.ArchetypeGenerationFailure: Error merging velocity templates: Encountered "?}." at line 15, column 110 of archetype-resources/assembly.xml
[ERROR] Was expecting one of:
[ERROR] "}" ...
[ERROR] <DOT> ...
```

when I use the same changes on an actual project assembly.xml this complies fine, gives issue only in the archetype project. Which is strange. I was expecting Maven to not worry about archetype-resources at all.

**edit**
default value of outputFileNameMapping is `${artifact.artifactId}-${artifact.version}${dashClassifier?}.${artifact.extension}` . All I did was change `version` to `baseVersion`. [dependencySet](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#dependencySet)

Comment: It's telling you the ? is unexpected... what is it there for?

Comment: default value is ` ${artifact.artifactId}-${artifact.version}${dashClassifier?}.${artifact.extension} ` . All I did was change `version` to `baseVersion`. [dependencySet](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#dependencySet)